# How to run a function simultaneously multiple times, passing parameter to divs that has the same class name

Tags: javascript

I simplify my code to be understood easly. I want to run an animation function passing the value of div ath the same time. When I put it in loop, I can do nothing. Interval continues, error messages etc.

I must see this output if it works correctly.

"30, 60, 90, 1. dial => i: 0, val: 60, 2. dial => i: 0, val: 60, 3. dial => i: 0, val: 90, 1. dial => i: 1, val: 30, 2. dial => i: 1, val: 60, 3. dial => i: 1, val: 90, 1. dial => i: 2, val: 30, 2. dial => i: 2, val: 60, ..."

I changed the view to be printed correctly. :(

```js
var result = document.querySelector(".result");
var dial = document.querySelectorAll('.dial');
var i = j = x = 0;
var val;

for (x = 0; x < dial.length; x++) {
  secDiv = dial[x].querySelector('.itemContainer > .sq');
  val = dial[x].querySelector('.itemContainer > span').getAttribute("per");
  result.innerHTML += val + ", ";

  //myInterval = setInterval(function() { cevir(x); }, 25);  // This is the line what I get errors  
}

myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  cevir(1);
}, 25);

function cevir(m) {
  dial = document.querySelectorAll('.dial');
  var val = dial[m].querySelector('span').getAttribute("per");
  result.innerHTML += "<br/> " + m + ". dial =>  i: " + i + ", val: " + val;

  if (i < val) {
    dial[m].querySelector('.sq').style.opacity = (i / 100);
    dial[m].querySelector('.sq').style.transform = "rotate(" + (i * 2) + "deg)";
  } else if (i == val) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
  i++;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'exo 2', sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #2ecc71, #16a085);
}

.dial {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.itemContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sq {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.result {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  //background-color : silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="dial">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <span per="30"></span>
    <div class="sq">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dial">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <span per="60"></span>
    <div class="sq">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dial">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <span per="90"></span>
    <div class="sq"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: 0


Thank you very much. I'm not good on JS. I just work to know. I know I have a mistake but... :) This will be very helpful. Thans again...

Comment: I noticed a problem. Still  i value is not advance properly? İt must be unique for all functions?

Answer (score 3):

There were a couple of mistakes. Please see the comments in the fixed code below:

```js
var result = document.querySelector(".result");
var dial = document.querySelectorAll('.dial');
var i = j = /*x =*/ 0; // <---------------- don't declare x here
var val;

//     declare it here
for (let x = 0; x < dial.length; x++) {
  val = dial[x].querySelector('.itemContainer > span').getAttribute("per");
  result.innerHTML += val + ", ";
  //  declare your interval here       &     pass it here 
  const myInterval = setInterval(function() { cevir(x, myInterval); }, 25);
}

// so it is passed here 
function cevir(m, myInterval) {
  dial = document.querySelectorAll('.dial');
  var val = dial[m].querySelector('span').getAttribute("per");
  result.innerHTML += "<br/> " + m + ". dial =>  i: " + i + ", val: " + val;

  if (i < val) {
    dial[m].querySelector('.sq').style.opacity = (i / 100);
    dial[m].querySelector('.sq').style.transform = "rotate(" + (i * 2) + "deg)";
  } else if (i == val) {
    // And accessible here 
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
  i++;
}
```

```html
<!-- Unchanged HTML & CSS -->                                                                                                                                               <div class="dial"><div class="itemContainer"> <span per="30"></span><div class="sq"></div></div></div><div class="dial"><div class="itemContainer"> <span per="60"></span><div class="sq"></div></div></div><div class="dial"><div class="itemContainer"> <span per="90"></span><div class="sq"></div></div></div><div class="result"></div><style>*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:'exo 2',sans-serif}body{width:100%;height:100vh;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;background:linear-gradient(45deg,#2ecc71,#16a085)}.dial{position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;margin:0 10px 0 10px}.itemContainer{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;border-radius:50%;background-color:#fff}.sq{position:absolute;background-color:red;width:70%;height:70%;opacity:0}.result{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;padding:5px}</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the interval inside the cevir function. Also if you want to print:

> 0. dial => i: 0, val: 30
> 1. dial => i: 0, val: 60
> 2. dial => i: 0, val: 90
> 3. dial => i: 1, val: 30
> 4. dial => i: 1, val: 60
> 5. dial => i: 1, val: 90

You need to create a `for...loop` inside cevir function and move `i` variable to the function scope:

```js
const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const dial = document.querySelectorAll(".dial");

for (let x = 0; x < dial.length; x++) {
  cevir(x);
}


async function cevir(m) {
  const myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    const val = dial[m].querySelector("span").getAttribute("per");

    [...Array(Number(val))].forEach((_, i) => {
      const update = () => {
        result.innerHTML += "<br/> " + m + ". dial =>  i: " + i + ", val: " + val;
        dial[m].querySelector(".sq").style.opacity = i / 100;
        dial[m].querySelector(".sq").style.transform = "rotate(" + i * 2 + "deg)";
      }
      await (update, i * 10);
    });
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, 25);
}

const await = (fn, t) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
  fn();
  resolve()
}, t));
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:'exo 2',sans-serif}body{width:100%;height:100vh;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;background:linear-gradient(45deg,#2ecc71,#16a085)}.dial{position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;margin:0 10px 0 10px}.itemContainer{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;border-radius:50%;background-color:#fff}.sq{position:absolute;background-color:red;width:70%;height:70%;opacity:0}.result{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;padding:5px}
```

```html
<!-- Unchanged HTML & CSS --> <div class="dial"> <div class="itemContainer"> <span per="30"></span> <div class="sq"> </div> </div></div><div class="dial"> <div class="itemContainer"> <span per="60"></span> <div class="sq"> </div> </div></div><div class="dial"> <div class="itemContainer"> <span per="90"></span> <div class="sq"></div> </div></div><div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make any change... Anyway I don't want to disturb you more. Thansk a lot for your kindness.

Comment: I'm sorry, I started working on your code and I didn't realize that someone had answered

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ysqkab?file=index.js

Comment: There is problem. The i value increase continiously. For each "dial" it must be added 1.

Comment: I understand now,  I fixed, see, https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ysqkab?file=index.js

Comment: This is so complex for me. :) I added a "j" varç  initial value=0. Add 1 for every call of func. If it is equal to "length", I increase "i", reset "j" again. :) Thank you very much...

Comment: I am happy to help ;)